# Spring cloud stream and async process

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have below simple consumer app. I wonder how to make it so that consumer pull the next message only after the current async process is completed

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application  {
    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> test() {
        return url -> {
            return WebClient
             .builder()
             .baseUrl(url)
             .retrieve()
             .bodyToMono(String.class)
             .map(data -> {
                // process data
                // pull the next message
             })
        }
    }
}
```

Follow up question:
How to handle this in processor app

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application  {
    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> test() {
        return url -> {
            return WebClient
             .builder()
             .baseUrl(url)
             .retrieve()
             .bodyToMono(String.class)
             .map(data -> {
                // output the data and pull the next message
             })
        }
    }
}
```